# Don't want webpack to replace require function

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am building a Windows App using [Electron](https://github.com/atom/electron). As Electron can parse `require` function like `var React = require('react');`, so I don't want webpack to replace `require` function with its own implementation for browser. How can I fix that?

Comment: webpack is a module bundler that works through the `require` semantics. If you're not using that functionality, then you're essentially not using webpack :) Is there a reason you need to use webpack with Electron? Electron can do the "bundling" for you since it's running Node under the hood.

Comment: Yeah, got it, thanks~